# Cron job to delete all files older than 7 days with extension in a specific folder - not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job that runs at midnight to delete all .txt files in a folder that are older than 7 days. I can see the job is running, but the files still exist in the folder.

I'm new to cron, so I'd really appreciate someone pointing out where I've gone wrong, or how to diagnose it if not obvious.

Here's my code with the directories obscured:

```
0 0 * * * bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Can you add the output of the complete command when you run it in your terminal directly?
Also, you should check the path to the find binary with 'which find' to make sure it's right as it seems it's missing a '/'

Comment: Is that path a typo?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- simply use 'find' or use the absolute path starting with / (for ubuntu it is /usr/bin/find)
- if you want to delete files, do not use 'rm -r'

This one works fine:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks heiko. Am I right that I can leave 'usr' as it is, or do I need to replace that with the name of the user I'm logged in as (which is root)?

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview - /usr/ is a default linux path... type "which find" to see the location of the find command on your system!

Comment: Any reasons why you wouldn't use -delete?

Comment: Will /usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -execdir rm -f {} \; give the same result?

Answer (score 3):

Or even more simple:`0 0 * * * /usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -delete`

Explained in:man find,  ACTIONS  -delete

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault! I suggest to give more details, what is your config doing and how.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A explanation and some details would be very helpful.

Comment: @HvdW Can you please explain the advantages of using -delete over rm? Found many answers on the internet, but none of them satisfactory. Also is there any downside to using delete? An example would do

Comment: `-delete` is just simpler, you don't have to fight with quoting and escape characters.